# Import of optional module with type information

Tags: typescript

I have an `optionalDependency` in my TypeScript library that might or might not be installed by users. This optional dependency is also written in TypeScript.

The way I handle it now is like this

#### 1.

```js
let lib: any;
try {
  lib = require('lib');
} catch (_) {}

if (lib) {
  // use lib
}
```

But this does not preserve type information. In an ideal world I would like to be able to do this:

#### 2.

```js
import { func } from 'lib';

if (func) {
  // use func
}
```

I have realised this is not possible.

So my question is: Is it possible to get type information from an optional dependency using the code in (1)? How?

Answer (score 0):

For me `skipLibCheck: true` in `tsconfig.json` option helped. This will make `tsc` check only files that are imported, so in my case, I don't import the file I had the error.

- https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#skipLibCheck:

> Skip type checking of declaration files.
>
> This can save time during compilation at the expense of type-system accuracy. For example, two libraries could define two copies of the same type in an inconsistent way. Rather than doing a full check of all d.ts files, TypeScript will type check the code you specifically refer to in your app’s source code.